# Find partial keywords in python list

Tags: python, list

```
x = 'a'
list = ['ab','cd','a']
if x in list:
    print(list.index(x))
```

Here I try to find all the values in list which contains 'a'. But with the 'in' method I can only find the value which is 'a' rather than contain 'a',like 'ab'. Are there any efficient ways to do so? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the spacing in the code after the `if`.!!

Comment: Just iterate the list.  And avoid using builtins as variables, i.e. change `list` to `lst` or `list_`

Answer (score 1):

Requires a list comprehension to get it done -

```
x = 'a'
list_ = ['ab','cd','a']
filtered_list = [elem for elem in list_ if x in elem]
print(filtered_list)
```

Output -

```
['ab', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop for this. Loop through the list and for each element in the list check whether your `x` is a substring of that element with `in`. If it is true display that element.

You can do it in python like this..

```
x = 'a'
list = ['ab','cd','a']

for element in list:
    if x in element:
        print(element)

Output
ab
a
```